# Non-Latin numbered lists (MS Word)

Tags: microsoft-word, language, microsoft-word-2013

(Sorry if duplicate)

When creating a numbered list in MS Word 2013, I can choose the list style, e.g.,

```
1. First item
2. Second item
3. Third item
```

or

```
a) First item
b) Second item
c) Third item
```

But can I get letters in a non Latin script, like this (Cyrillic):

```
а) First item
б) Second item
в) Third item
```

I am hoping that I am just missing something, surely there are many, many people in need of this. I've installed the language pack, set Windows locale. I did notice that after installing the language pack the list style which has text labels (First, Second, Third...) has changed language, but single letter style didn't.

Only thing I managed to find is [this person](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/outlined-number-lists-in-russian.3241115/) claiming to have seen this in Word 2003.

**UPDATE (2018-11-18):**

3.5 years later, I've made progress, by accident. I'm now using Word 2016 on Windows 10. I opened "Define New Multilevel List..." window, and in the "Number style for this list:" dropdown there were cyrillic styles (а, б, в... and А, Б, В...) but near the bottom of the list. I tested it and found it was not Serbian Cyrillic letters and ordering (the kind I need) but Russian. My Office has English UI, Windows is Serbian, locale is Serbian, only Russian thing is Russian keyboard layout (among others).

Comment: Does this link help?  http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-word/cyrillic-numbered-list/1d2ce09a-43c0-4f21-a251-7add37ee267b?auth=1